# rvalue reference as map template parameter

Tags: c++, stdmap, rvalue-reference

I'm new to `rvalue reference` and `std::move` concept. I have tried to create `std::map` which its second template parameter is an rvalue reference.

I have this DebugClass:

```cpp
class DebugClass
{
public:
    int num;

    DebugClass() = delete;
    DebugClass(const DebugClass& rhs) = delete;
    DebugClass& operator=(const DebugClass& rhs) = delete;

    DebugClass(int num) : num(num)
    {
        printf("constructor\n");
    }

    DebugClass(DebugClass&& rhs)
    {
        printf("move constructor\n");
        this->num = rhs.num;
    }

    DebugClass& operator=(const DebugClass&& rhs)
    {
        printf("rvalue assignment\n");
        this->num = rhs.num;
    }
};
```

This is how I use it:

```cpp
void foo(DebugClass&& dbgClass)
{
    std::map<uint32_t, DebugClass&&> myMap;
    myMap.insert(std::pair<uint32_t, DebugClass&&>(1, std::move(dbgClass)));
    printf("%d\n", myMap[1].num);
}


int main()
{
    foo(DebugClass(2));
}
```

I want to be able to see this output:

```
constructor
move constructor
2
```

But instead I get a compilation error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2832   'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::second': a reference type cannot be value-initialized   Tests   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\tuple   1304
```

How can I move my `foo`'s parameter into `myMap`?

Comment: You cannot store references in container, because reference is not an object, it is alias referring to already-existing object. Container like `map` can store only other objects.

Comment: @rafix07 - So how can change that code so the wanted output will be printed?

Comment: [Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vHX4xQ), because `DebugClass` is not default-constructible, you cannot use `map::operator[]` instead, `find` was used.

Comment: @rafix07 great! thank you